# Write to eMMC boot0 partition from u-boot

Tags: u-boot, mmc

I am using eMMC based on 5.1 Version, which has boot0, boot1, rpmb and userarea.

```
Inorder to write to eMMC from u-boot, mmc commands can be used.

mmc read commands is of below form.

$mmc read addr blk# cnt

if i give blk to 0x0, where it will write boot0 partition or user area ?

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Got the answer, if we use mmc dev command from u-boot it can switch to boot0,boot1 and user area. Example mmc dev 0 0 user area mmc dev 0 1 boot0